# Рандомное появление платформ Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой, писал код для того чтобы платформы рандомно появлялись не совсем далеком друг от друга и был какой-то разброс, но получилось все на оборот! Помогите решить задачу, если не трудно.

```
void Start()
{
        Vector3 spawner = new Vector3();
        for(int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
        {
            spawner.x = Random.Range(-1.7f, 1.7f); 
            spawner.y += Random.Range(2f, 4f);
            Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawner, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Что именно пошло не так? Платформы не появляются или спавнятся но не рандомно?

Comment: `+=` заменить на `=`?

Comment: Я пробовал заменить на = но тогда платформы будут в одной куче сравниться.

Comment: Платформы спавнятся, но близко друг к другу и далеко от персонажа.